# Cross-Domain ajax error with bearer authentication - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, cors, http-status-code-401, request-headers

So... i'm making a cross domain (CORS) call. When i initially make it on the page, it works just fine (noting that cross-domain issues aren't really a problem), but when i make another request later to the same server adding a bearer authorization token to the header, it is failing with a 401 Unauthorized.

Also, when i run this code from the same domain, both calls run successfully (identifying that the token is ok...)

Thoughts?

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiPath.userMetaUrl(),
  xhrFields: { 
    withCredentials: true 
  },
  cache: false,
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log("url: " + apiPath.userMetaUrl());
    console.log("fn loadUserMetaData xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
    console.log("fn loadUserMetaData xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    console.log("fn loadUserMetaData thrownError: " + thrownError);
  },
  dataType: "json",
  jsonpCallback: "callback",
  beforeSend : setHeader,
  success: function (data) {
    //woohoo!
  }
}

function setHeader(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authenticatedInfo.access_token);
}
```

Again, running this code from same domain as apiPath.userMetaURL() works fine. On a different domain, the initial call without adding request header works fine. Access-Control-Allow-Orign has the cross-domain URL added. Access-Control-Allow-Headers has Authorization added.
xhr.status returns 0 and responseText/thrownError are blank.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP != ajax

These requests you are making are simply adding `<script>` tags to your DOM. It's just wrapped in an ajax syntax for ease of use. You can't modify the request headers in this fashion. You need to create a CORS ajax request, and configure your server to handle them.

Executing jsonp requests on the same domain though... I believe jQuery just uses an `xmlHttpRequest` though. For cross-domain, it uses `<script>` tags. This would explain the behavior you are seeing.

Consider the following.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com', 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar'); }
});
```

Look at your network traffic. It will create the request, but you will not see the `foo` header.

Comment: doesn't seem to make a difference. however, it does seem to be failing during the preflight OPTIONS request. looking into getting the server to allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests since those won't carry request headers...

Comment: How would this *not* make a difference? It absolutely does, you just seem to have other issues.

Comment: For the time I took researching your issues and providing at least a foundation, you could give some rep.